# Ansible playbook ERROR! the role 'Juniper.junos' was not found in /home/

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, yaml, juniper, junos-automation

Hello im trying to run this playbook at with ansible and im getting this output every time

ERROR! the role 'Juniper.junos' was not found in /home/pagdas/aja2/roles:/home/pagdas/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/home/pagdas/aja2

The error appears to be in '/home/pagdas/aja2/uptime.yaml': line 6, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
roles:
    - Juniper.junos
      ^ here
```

my play book is this

```
---
- name: Get device uptime
  hosts:
    - all
  roles:
    - Juniper.junos
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
    - name: username
      prompt: Junos Username
      private: no

    - name: password
      prompt: Junos Password
      private: yes

  tasks:
    - name: get uptime using galaxy module
      juniper_junos_command:
        commands:
          - show system uptime
        provider:
          host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
          port: 22
          user: "{{ username }}"
          passwd: "{{ password }}"
```

i have install this :
sudo ansible-galaxy collection install juniper.device

and this :
sudo ansible-galaxy install Juniper.junos

but is still getting this error can someone sort me out please ??

Answer (score 0):

Seem to have installed with "sudo" user. Do check if you are executing the ansible-playbook command with "sudo" or not.

Execute the playbook in verbose mode for more information. Append -vvv at the end of command.

It is recommended that you raise any issue with juniper.device or Juniper.junos at the github repository of the codebase for faster resolution [juniper.device](https://github.com/Juniper/ansible-junos-stdlib).